# Initialize array with length variable passed to method

Tags: c++, arrays, methods

I'm working on a program, and for one of the classes I pass a width and height to the constructor which then uses them to initialize an array to hold some data temporarily.

```
class NoiseDrawable : public Drawable {
    public:
        NoiseDrawable(const int width, const int height, Color color) : Drawable(width, height) {
            float heightMap[width][height];

            ....
```

Now the problem is that I'm getting an error where I use width and height to initialize the array:

```
expression must have constant value
```

Now I understand why I would be getting that error, and it make perfect sense. What I don't understand is why I still get it even after changing the passed integers to be constant!

How can I fix this?

Comment: VLA's aren't standard c++. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Ugh I was starting to guess as much, but was hoping to avoid using vectors since it get's messy dealing with 2d data

Comment: You can use a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>  heightMap(width,std::vector<float>(height));`

Comment: A 1 d vector is easy to use, and accessing it as if 2 d is also remarkably easy.  "size_t 1d_IndxFrom(int r, int c) { return static_cast<size_t>((r * maxCol) + c); }"

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid vector you could try this. Adds complexity and is a little ugly

```
float** heightMap = new int*[width];//create array of pointers (width many)

for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    heightMap[i] = new int[height];//add turn each pointer into a float array (height long)
```

***edit*** this will require some manual memory clean up

Comment: Not only do you have to manually manage the memory, but this isn't even the same as the original method since the data is not contiguous.